# Is there a KML or similar file that shows all of the CQ Zones?

Tags: location, cq-zones, map

I'm wanting to view the CQ Zones in Google Earth, and I understand that a KML file will allow me to do so. Is there a place where I can get a KML file that shows all of the CQ Zones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not any such listing, as the definitions for CQ zones are a bit ambiguous. The official definitions can be found at the [CQ Magazine WAZ award definition](http://www.cq-amateur-radio.com/cq_awards/cq_waz_awards/cq_waz_list.html). Areas like the ocean aren't covered, otherwise it's a fairly simple geography lookup to get the areas defined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is now. This is probably what you want.

https://g7vjr.org/2019/08/google-earth-kmz-files-for-cq-zones-and-itu-zones/

Comment: Thanks for posting these! The StackExchange sites usually discourage "link only answers" but in this case I don't know what more needs to be said :-)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.hamatlas.eu/Gg/KML_en.htm) may be helpful.  Specifically the link titled "Map of QTH Locators for whole World".  I was able to successfully determine my grid square using it and it covers the globe.

Comment: That's just grid squares, not CQ zones...